# d3js not formatting text value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am trying to format the values that are showing up on the chart, but for somereason, it is not updating.

Here is the link that I am working with:

https://plnkr.co/edit/naP7XXkNcaxSJRmpTQv5?p=preview

In the box2.js file line 206 is where the values for the box are showing up.

```
  var boxTick = g.selectAll("text.box")
      .data(quartileData);
 if(showLabels == true) {
  boxTick.enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "box")
      .attr("dy", ".3em")
      .attr("dx", function(d, i) { return i & 1 ? 6 : -6 })
      .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i & 1 ?  + width : 0 })
      .attr("y", x0)
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d, i) { return i & 1 ? "start" : "end"; })
      .text(format)
    .transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("y", x1);
}
```

I have tried changing the `.text()` to different things but it always gives the same result.

Comment: Are you wanting to apply the formatting to the text? `.text(function(d) { return format(d);})`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the error was that I was not replacing all the locations where `.text()` was set.

The `.transition()` had to be updated also. The same thing applies for the whiskers code.

```
  boxTick.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .text(format)
      .attr("y", x1);
```